# Filling a column with its header value

Tags: python

How would I be able to create a new column `D` and fill it with it's respective header value (i.e. not set as just `D`, but any value that is passed as a column header)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [1, 2, 3], 'C': [4, 5, 6]})
```

#### Output:

```
index   B   C   D
0       1   4   D
1       2   5   D
2       3   6   D
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is the following (if you know at hand what is the header):

```
df['D'] = 'D'

>>> df
   B  C  D
0  1  4  D
1  2  5  D
2  3  6  D
```

Or if your `'D'` column is initially empty, e.g.

```
>>> df
   B  C D
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

then the following works too:

```
header = list(df.columns)[-1]
df[header] = header

>>> df
   B  C  D
0  1  4  D
1  2  5  D
2  3  6  D
```